# How to catch timeout/errors in a CURL shell script?

Tags: bash, http, shell, curl

I want to issue a cURL GET request to a URL and based on the return HTTP code decide whether to do something with the returned HTTP data.

For example, if the HTTP code for a certain url request through cURL is valid (not timed out or error), then keep the returned data from the request somewhere in my system.

How can I actually 'catch' the returned HTTP code (or timeout) and do the decision based on that?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924422/how-do-i-determine-if-a-web-page-exists-with-shell-scripting) is closely related...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Execute following as `script.sh http://www.google.com/`.
`-D` - dump headers to file
`-o` - write response to file
`-s` - be silent
`-w` - display value of specified variables

```bash
#!/bin/bash

RESPONSE=response.txt
HEADERS=headers.txt

status=$(curl -s -w %{http_code} $1 -o $RESPONSE)

# or
#curl -s -D $HEADERS $1 -o $RESPONSE
#status=$(cat $HEADERS | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')

echo $status
```

Use `$status` and `$RESPONSE` for further processing.

Comment: +1 for including explanation of the CLI options. They're in the man file, but it's nice to have that extra level of abstraction removed with just a small amount of work on the poster's part. I wish more people would do this.

Comment: Is the % sign windows specific?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen % sign is not windows specific. Predefined variables, that are available for `-w` option of `curl`, are passed using `%{variable_name}` format. In order to run in windows, will have to manually escape % sign. From `curl` man page - `NOTE: The %-symbol is a special symbol in the win32-environment, where all occurrences of % must be doubled when using this option.`

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to store the http response to a variable.

```bash
#!bin/bash

STATUS_RECEIVED=$(curl -s --write-out "%{http_code}\n" $envUrl --output output.txt --silent) ;

echo $STATUS_RECEIVED
```