# Awk Regex: match any first character

Tags: regex, bash, awk, gawk

I'm trying to create a more effective "check if URL exist" function and I'm almost done the only roadblock is the regex.

So I'm looking for a regex that will match any first character of an output then print it and exit 
for example the bellow code gets the source code of the youtube page and as soon as the output reaches the title tags it matches them and it kills the wget commands

Idea borrowed from here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103252/how-do-i-get-a-websites-title-using-command-line

> **Performance/Efficiency**
>
> Here, out of laziness, we have perl read the whole content in memory
>   before starting to look for the  tag. Given that the title is
>   found in the  section that is in the first few bytes of the
>   file, that's not optimal. A better approach, if GNU awk is available
>   on your system could be:
>
> ```
> wget -qO- 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc' | \
> gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v RS='</title' 'RT{gsub(/.*<title[^>]*>/,"");print;exit}'
> ```
>
> That way, awk stops reading
>   after the first

My logic is this: if the URL exist it will output source and I don't want to waste time by downloading the entire source code thus on the first character of source code output, print it and exit.

then I will store the output of wget and gawk

```
first_character_of_source_code=$(wget|awk magic)
if [[ $first_character_of_source_code != '' ]]; then
    echo "URL exists!"
else
    echo "URL doesn't exist!"
fi
```

Also for my "check if URL exist" function I've tried this [How do I determine if a web page exists with shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924422/how-do-i-determine-if-a-web-page-exists-with-shell-scripting) 
the curl solution suggested in the answers is mostly ok but website like Quora return 403 Forbidden, and yes I've added user agent but the wget plus gawk solution return source code which is better for determining if the URL exists.

Comment: Yes, a down vote, just what I needed

Comment: `... | cut -c1` will give you the first char.  `awk` equivalent can be `... | awk '{print $1}' FS=""`

Comment: @karakfa thank but I want the command to exit after matching the first character can I this be done

Comment: Thanks @karakfa I found the solution thanks to your suggestion

Comment: @karakfa you are a genius thanks, I improved your suggestion and I found my solution to the problem `awk '{print $1;exit}' FS=""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weren't so committed to using awk, you could have done it quickly and easily with `grep`:

```
if wget -qO - https://stackoverflow.com/ | grep -q ""
then
  echo "wget returned at least one character."
fi
```

Comment: ok I've tested your code and it seems to work equally good as mine. I used the `time` command to compare both. BTW, I was committed to using awk because I didn't know that this could be done with any other command. Actually I will accept your answer because I want to give somebody a reputation for helping me.

Comment: I'm basically a beginner and I don't know a lot of commands and stuff. Thinking it now, your solution might be more robust and reliable then mine

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to @karakfa for the suggestion

match the first character of an output, print it and exit

```
echo "Yes, a down vote, just what I needed" | awk '{print $1;exit}' FS=""
# It will print
Y
```

Full source code of my script
`check_URL.sh` (working perfectly)

```
# Variables
URL="$*"
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"

# Main program
first_character_of_source_code=$(wget -e robots=off --user-agent="$user_agent" -qO- "$URL" | \
awk '{print $1;exit}' FS="")

if [[ $first_character_of_source_code != '' ]]; then
    echo "URL exists!"
    exit 0
else
    echo "URL doesn't exist!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Note that this won't work the way you plan to use it for binary files starting with NUL bytes (like non-hybrid ISOs).

Comment: @thatotherguy check my answer I posted the full source code of my script. In my script I will be working with website's source code _binary files starting with NUL bytes (like non-hybrid ISOs)_ is this relevant to website's source code can you show an example web page that won't work. Anyway, thanks for your input!